# Where to store large application data on android devices?

Tags: android, security, object, store

I'm currently facing a problem where I should store my object structure on the android device.

The usecase: I'm starting a call to an applicationserver (with the great help of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)), get a well known response (xml-response) from the server, parse the data and transform it finally into my object structure (highly complex class diagram with many associations between the classes). So far it's working, thanks to the great XMLPullParser ;)
I'm wondering where to store (and of course share) the fetched data between my activities... I already know that I can use sqlite, but I do not have an or-mapper (like hibernate in the j2ee environment). I'm also not allowed to store this sensitive data on the device (in sqlite or file system), so my first approach was to store this data in a singleton (which is of cource being held in memory...). But what happens when system is getting on low memory, can android "destroy" the data stored in my singleton? I already read about extending the [android.app.Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class... So what is the best way to securely store object data (called from "webservice") on android devices?

BTW: Android development is that cool! We are currently porting a Windows Mobile 6.5 App to Android and iPhone, and my colleague (reponsible for iPhone-dev) is complaining all the time^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding an OR mapper, I came across [OrmLite](http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/) the other day. It is a general ORM tool for Java, but it also has some special adaptations that makes it work for [Android](http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/sqlite_java_android_orm.html). I haven't had time to test it myself yet, but it looks promising :)

As for storing sensitive data on the phone, you really don't have the option of storing it only in memory (using some kind of singleton as you suggested). As soon as your application goes to the background, it can be killed instantaneously, so you *have* to persist what data you want to keep in some way. That being said, if you save data to [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), this will not be available for any other app on the phone (given that the phone is not rooted, because if is rooted this is easy to get around). I do believe that this same goes for data you store using SQLite, but I'm not 100% certain, so I won't guarantee it.

But basically, if you are sure that your app will only run on non-rooted devices, you should be pretty safe saving your data to Internal Storage. And if that isn't good enough, there there is the [javax.crypto](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html) package, but I've never used that so I can't really say anything about it.

Comment: Hi Nailuj, thanks for your detailed answer! So I think the only way is to store the data by extending the android.app.Application class because this is the only chance where I can "securely" store fetched data on low memory (using my own implementation of a singleton won't know when system kills the application). What about serializing the data and store them with javax.crypto in filesystem and reload that data when memory is available (or application state is restored)?

Comment: @tim.kaufner: yes, that is why I mentioned `javax.crypto`. If nothing else is a "secure enough" solution, you can use that to encrypt your data and store it to Internal Storage (or an SQLite database for that matter). Other than that you add an extra layer of encryption/decryption, it is not really any different for the way you normally would handle state in an Android application (persist any data you want to keep in `onPause()` and reload it in `onCreate()` etc).

Comment: I will give it a try :) Also thanks for mentioning the OrmLite library, didn't know there was a "portable" OR-mapper, but I prefer storing the data on the filesystem or (if mounted) on the external sd-card. But I'm not sure if serialize/deserialize of large object sets is fast on this kind of devices... I'll try it and see what happens :)